# Microsoft Access 2013 Record Source Columns

Tags: ms-office, ms-access-2013

I recently got tasked with customizing a report in an access database, I havent touched access in years so its a little rusty for me. I have successfully added the Fields to the table, added them to the form and added them to the report. If i run the report they query correctly. But all the other fields on the report are setup with an expression such as:

=IIF([Mold Temp High]=0,"----",[Mold Temp High])

Now the expression makes 100% to me but when it auto populates the field, such as Mold Temp High, for all the previous fields i can see they show up as Record Source Column fields, but for any new field i have added shows up as a Text Box.

If i create an expression with the new fields i get a Circular Reference and it shows #type on the report instead of the value.

Just curious to why the new fields show up as TextBoxs and not Record Sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are dragging the new fields from the field list.  When you do this, it creates the text box with the exact same name as the data field.  So when you use this name in an expression, it thinks you are referencing the text box object.  To prevent this problem, make sure that every time you create a new textbox (or any control) from a data field that you name it something different by setting the Name property of the text box.  Generally I just add "txt" to the front of the field name.  This will ensure that you are always explicitly referring to either the textbox name or the data field name.

Comment: I believe I have tried both Dragging onto the report and also creating a text box but I could be wrong. I will check this out.

Comment: I think it was a combination of me expecting the Record Source to be one way (using a query named Process Sheet Report Query) but instead having a custom SQL select statement, that wasnt pulling any changes I was making and what you proposed. Thank you! it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your logic around a bit..

We remember, IIF is constructed as:

```
=IIF((Some_Table_Field or value),True-condition,False-condtion)
```

You maybe looking at:

```
=IIF([Mold Temp High]=NULL,"----",[Mold Temp High])
```

Or, maybe (use ISNULL or ISBLANK it has been a while for Access with me as well):

```
=IIF(isnull([Mold Temp High]),"----",[Mold Temp High])
```

Or, rather:

```
=IIF([Mold Temp High]<1,"----",[Mold Temp High])
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this is not really more about my expression as i know that it is correct, but more about why it pulls a text box field instead of a record source column. But i do appreciate your information.